# What is the default date of Fireborn?

Tags: campaign-settings, time, fireborn

From what I see is that 2001 magic came back.
But what I didn't find is when the usual Fireborn game is mostly meant to be set date wise (neither in the published adventure nor in the infos in game).

As most games of that time ususally had such a date I'm wondering there what the default date for Fireborn is meant to be?
*(Thus is there any info in the books somewhere I'm missing the whole time?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default date of Fireborn is **somewhere in the late 2000s**, so in the neighbourhood of 2008 or so. We can see this from its publication date (2004) and how its description of the dual settings references the “now” of its own publication (Fireborn PHB, p. 3; emphasis mine):

> The action in Fireborn takes place in both **the modern day** and a mythic age. The base setting for campaigns is **modern London just a few years from now**…

Comment: Tnx means then I have confused it a bit with shadowrun when I thought that a concrete date was given^^